# Segue from ViewController to TabBarController

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I am a newbie to Swift and I try to perform the simplest task to imagine: Establish a segue from normal `ViewController` to `TabBarController`.

I've already given the segue an `Identifier` ( "intoGame" ) and created an `IBAction` in the `ViewController`.

Everything's fine, no build time errors, but when I tap on the `Button` nothing happens.

When I establish the `TabBarController` as initial view, it is displayed correct and fully functional.

I am out of ideas and help would be much appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you connect `IBAction` method with button?

Comment: Yes, I did connect the Action with the Button.

Comment: I have checked on my machine and it works. Put a debugger in ```IBAction``` method and also print something in it. Then check in the console if it prints or not.

Comment: Finally it worked. I checked the shortcut again and it only contained "Exit". not the function itself. I don't know why but now it is all fine.